# 500 Internal Server Error on W3C validator

Tags: w3c-validation, internal-server-error

When I try to validate my website www.flowers-for-you.nl I get a 500 Internal Server Error. The website does render normal in any browser.

How do I find and solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

It is rendered by browser, but status code of response is 500. You can see it in firebug (see screen). Maybe you set header 500 in your page scripts?

> header("HTTP/1.0 500 Attacked by ninja");

Or maybe there is some error in your page scripts - watch your backend logs:)

[image]